# How to order a reverse foreign key in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following `for` loop I create in my template:

```
    {% for task in item.task_set.all %}
        <li class="task">
            {{ task }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to order the task_set. It currently orders by ID but I would like to order it by name of the task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are happy for your tasks to always be ordered by the name of the task, use the [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) option

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

If you want a different ordering than the model's default ordering, you could set the order of tasks in your view, then iterate through `tasks` in your template.

```
# view
tasks = item.task_set.order_by('name')

# template
{% for task in tasks %}
```

It's not possible to change the ordering in the template, because you can't pass arguments to `{{ item.task_set.order_by }}`. If you really need to specify the order of a queryset in the template, you'll need to write a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters).